# c# MVC No column name was specified error when ordering by count

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an auctions' website built in MVC. The `_context` object is my DbContext. I contruct the query in such way:

```
IQueryable<Auctions> query = _context.Auctions.Where(a => a.state == 
"active").Include(a => a.AuctionsUsersWatching).Include(a => a.bids);
```

(includes are for who watches which auction and for auction bids)

When returning the results to the view, I want to sort them by a specific column. Sorting works fine for all the fields of and Auction but does not work for the count of auction's bids:

```
case order_by_bidCount: 
   query = (order == "asc") ? query.OrderBy(c => c.bids.Count()).AsQueryable() 
 : query.OrderByDescending(c => c.bids.Count()).AsQueryable();
```

The problem is, this portion of code gives me an SqlException `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.`. This obviously means a lack of an alias in SQL. I know ow to fix this in SQL, but I want to know how to fix this in MVC. Thanks for any help!

Comment: in your `query` declaration you're using `a` as your accessor but in your switch case you're using `c` as your accessor. I'm unsure if that's the issue, but could be a start?

Comment: Could you use group by instead of count? First group by then orderby? I don't think .count() inside the lambda translates to valid SQL.

Comment: count seems to be returning a number, a single number not rows of numbers. so there's nothing to order by. If you group by you can then order by the aggregate column

Answer (score 0):

Could you use group by instead of count? First group by then orderby? I don't think .count() inside the lambda translates to valid SQL.

From MSDN:

> Some query operations, such as Count or Max, have no equivalent query
>   expression clause and must therefore be expressed as a method call.
>   Method syntax can be combined with query syntax in various ways.

EDIT

I'm assuming 'query' will look something like:

```
Auction ID     Item Name      Bid Id
Auction 4      "Red Car"      bid5
Auction 4      "Red Car"      bid2
Auction 4      "Red Car"      bid1 
Auction 3      "Stereo"       bid3
Auction 7      "Watch"        bid4
Auction 7      "Watch"        bid6
```

So you could try:

```
query.GroupBy(c => c.Auctions)
     .Select (n => new 
                   {
                       Auction = n.Key,
                       AuctionCount = n.Count()
                   }
              )
     .OrderBy(n => n.AuctionCount)
```

What I am trying to achieve here is the group by will group the items based off the auctions, something like (assuming the Auction is the same and bids are different in the 'query')

```
(Auction 4), [bid1, bid2, bid5] 
(Auction 3), [bid3]
(Auction 7), [bid4, bid6]
```

The Select will project these groups into new objects that look something like

```
**Auction**    **AuctionCount**
Auction 4       3
Auction 3       1
Auction 7       2
```

Then we can order by the AuctionCount.

Since I don't know what your data looks like (specifically what the 'query' result looks like), I can only guess as to how this should work. But hopefully theres enough info there to customise for your needs.

Comment: Could you provide a example? Because I want the result (the variable query) not to change.

Comment: Well I am sorry for not being specific, I have a table of Auctions AND a table of Bids connected to an auction. They are connected by EF7, so every auction has a virtual list of bids that belong to it. I want to sort Auctions by the number of Bids.

Comment: I tried query.Select(n => new { N = n, NumberOfBids = n.bids.Count() }).OrderBy(c => c.Count).Select(n => n.N).AsQueryable();  but it gives me the same mistake

Comment: Why are you ordering by c.count? Since you've projected into a new sequence with N and NumberOfBids as properties, you should orderby c.NumberOfBids. Rather than trying to do it in one statement, break it up first into multiple with break points at each step. 1.var x = query.Select(n => new { N = n, NumberOfBids = n.bids.Count() }) 2.var y = x.OrderBy(c => c.NumberOfBids) 3. var z = y.Select(n => n.N).AsQueryable(). Set a breakpoint at each step and see what the results are. Once its working put it back together into a single statement. Don't forget to try with groupby as well :)